# How to check that last test is failed?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, tap

I test my code via [`Test2::V0`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::V0)

```
is $result, 'value', 'Test OK';
```

Can I check that last test is failed?

In mojolicious, for example, there is [`->or(sub{ ... })`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Test/Mojo#or)

Does `Test2::V0` have something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test functions have return values -- a true value or a false value depending on the outcome of the test -- which can be captured or checked.

```
if (! is $result, 'value', 'Test Ok') {
    warn "Test 42 failed. Skip test 43\n";
}

is $result, 'value', 'Test Ok'
    or warn "Test 42 failed. Skip test 43\n";

$z1 = is $result1, 'value1';
$z2 = is $result2, 'value2';
$z3 = is $result3, 'value3';
if (!!$z1 + !!$z2 + !!$z3 >= 2) {
    print "At least two of the previous three tests passed!\n";
}
```